# Some simle limits

Tags: limits

I want to find limits:

$\lim \frac{(2 n) !}{5^{2(n - 3 [\frac{n}{3}])}(6[\frac{n}{3}])!}$ for $n = 3k + 0,1,2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for $n=3 k+1$ you are missing a factor of $(6/5)^2$, and for $n=3 k+2$ you are missing a factor of $(6/5)^4$.

Comment: @GH: something like that.  What do you mean by "second asymptotic"?  Higher order expansion?

Comment: In the second one, why are you applying Stirling's approximation to $k!$?  There was no info on the value of $k$.